# use return or print function

Tags: python

I am trying to chose 10 numbers between 1 and 100 using random function,but unfortunately I am having a problem to use whether return or print function.

Using return function does return me only a single number however if I use print function it gives me 5 numbers but a none is also printed after 5 numbers. I am really confused what to do?

Comment: Please upload your code attempts, it helps us to understand your dilemma more

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and then edit your question to include all of the relevant information (including your code).

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it may help.

```
import random    
a = []    #take a list to store randomly generated values from the loop.
n = 10    
for i in range(n):
    a.append(random.randint(1,100))    
print("random number list is :",a)
```

Answer (score -1):

For the first approach(by returning value), you can store the randomly generated values in a list or tuple or set (whatever you like) and then return that sequence.( *Refer to @Devi Silparasetti's answer.* )

For the second approach (using the `print()` function) . Use print only in the function which prints those numbers. Don't try to print the function calling. Simply invoke function only.

For example-

```
def abc():
    print('abc')
abc()
```

Don't use `print(abc())` .

Answer (score -1):

I guess what you need is a *generator*:

```
def generate_random(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield random.randint(1,100)

print([x for x in generate_random(10)])
```

Generator returns multiple values one at a time. So you can consume these values per request.